# How to uninstall apps downloaded from internet in Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: uninstall

I am new to Ubuntu right now and i want to know how do we uninstall an app which i downloaded from the internet in this case a Facebook messenger called ftalk. I type this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove ftalk
```

but this is the answer:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

what should i do?it is driving me crazy

Answer (score 2):

"***...is another process using it?***"

If *Synaptic Package Manager* or other are running try closing them, and then run the command again.

Answer (score 1):

Exit software centre or any other software install programs before running it, rebooting may also help.

---

*Or try zurdo's answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/102084/178596):*

#### This should be used as last resource. If you use this carelessly you can end with a broken system. Please evaluate other answers first before trying this.

You can delete the lock file with the following command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

You may also need to delete the lock file in the cache directory

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

After that, try opening Synaptic again.